# How to browserify, compile ES6 and minify NodeJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I am trying to get to grips with browserify and ES6 simultaneously. I have the following basic Node files:

**main.js**

```
var foo = require('./foo.js');
var x = foo.math(200);
console.log(x);
```

**foo.js**

```
exports.math = (n)=>{ 
  return n * 111;
};
```

Now I want to do the following:

- Browserify this into a file `bundle.js` so I can include it as a script in my website
- Compile the JS using babel to make the ES6 readable by all browsers
- Minify `bundle.js` to improve load times in the browser

I have browserify installed globally and I run that with this command:
`browserify main.js > bundle.js`

Works great. But should I be running babel first? How do I complete my 3 step process and in what order (of course minification will have to happen last)? Should I be doing this all with grunt?

Comment: You should be doing this with grunt, and use browserify first.

Comment: Yes, you should use babel first, which seems to be a necessity when you'd use ES6 modules

Comment: 2 conflicting comments here about which task to run first...

Comment: @Coop Bergi is correct. Grunt isn't even required for ES6 transpilation or minification. You need to transpile your modules first using babel before browserify can even reason about bundling them. Anyway, take this misunderstanding as a sign that maybe you should slow down a little bit and take time to understand the tools you're using.

Comment: Browserify works with CommonJS modules. ES6 modules are not CommonJS, so they have to be converted to CommonJS first, which is what Babel does (among other things). Or you use a bundler that works on ES6 modules, such as https://github.com/rollup/rollup .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary anymore to use a task runner. However, use a neat plugin like `babelify` from command line as described in its `README.md` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify).

```
npm install --save-dev browserify babelify babel-preset-es2015

browserify script.js -o bundle.js \
    -t [ babelify --presets es2015 ]
```

And add other transforms as needed from [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/wiki/list-of-transforms) or any where else, e.g. `uglify`.

Comment: FWIW, uglify still does not support es6

Answer (score 1):

For es6 use [uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es), it supports ES6.

> npm install uglify-es -g

Answer (score 1):

[Uglify ES](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) has not been updated in a year and is not maintained and will probably not work. I suggest using [Terser](https://github.com/terser-js/terser) with a plugin like [uglifyify](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify) run the following to install uglifyify

```
npm i uglifyify
```

as of 2018 babelify needs @babel/core (babel 7) and a preset like @babel/preset-env

Install them like this:

```
npm i babelify @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

Finally

```
browserify \
-t [ babelify --presets [[ @babel/preset-env]]  \
-g uglifyify main.js > bundle.js
```